# Why I can't use the (cnt <- hGetContents h) expression instead of cnt?

Tags: haskell

I learn Haskell. It works fine:

```
import System.IO

main = do
  h <- openFile "text.txt" ReadMode
  cnt <- hGetContents h
  mapM_ putStrLn $ lines cnt
  hClose h
```

But this isn't working:

```
import System.IO

main = do
  h <- openFile "text.txt" ReadMode  
  mapM_ putStrLn $ lines (cnt <- hGetContents h)
  hClose h
```

Why my second variant isn't working? I expected both variants are equal, because the `(cnt <- hGetContents h)` is an expression and returns the value too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `cnt <- hGetContents h` is **not** an expression, it's some special syntax sugar inside [do notation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation). This means it is a different way of writing the following normal Haskell code:

```
hGetContents h >>= \ cnt -> {- rest of do block -}
```

The part before the `{- rest of the do block -}` is not a whole expression here, because the rest of the do block is needed to complete the lambda's body.

You could desugar it manually to get something like:

```
hGetContents h >>= \ cnt -> mapM_ putStrLn (lines cnt)
```

or the point-free version

```
hGetContents h >>= mapM_ putStrLn . lines
```

You can tell that it's a special expression because it introduces a new identifier (`cnt`) that you can use in the rest of your code, outside of the expression itself. This is not something that normal Haskell expressions get to do (at least without compile-time magic).

Answer (score 2):

`cnt <- hGetContents h` is essentially syntactical sugar for `hGetContents h >>= \cnt ->`.

It is *not* an expression, it is sugar intended for its own line in a do-block.

If you still want to keep it on one line, you can do this, though you will not be able to refer to the file's contents later on:

```
import System.IO

main = do
  h <- openFile "text.txt" ReadMode  
  hGetContents h >>= mapM_ putStrLn . lines
  hClose h
```